# Displaying info from previous loops in a label

Tags: vb.net

So I am supposed to get the previous iteration's answers from a `For Next` Loop and display in one label with multiple lines but I am unable to do so with the label displaying the most recent answer instead.

My code is down below:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
        Dim intScore As Integer
        Dim intTotal As Integer
        Dim intCounter As Integer
        Dim intAverage As Integer

        For intCounter = 1 To 5
            intScore = InputBox("Enter your grade to continue:", "What's your Grade?")
            If intScore < 1 Or intScore > 100 Then

                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a number between 1 and 100")

            End If

            intTotal = intScore + intTotal
            intAverage = intTotal / 5
            lblAnswers.Text = ("Your Grade is: " & intScore) + vbNewLine + ("Your Grade is: " & intScore) + vbNewLine + ("Your Grade is: " & intScore) + vbNewLine + ("Your Grade is: " & intScore) + vbNewLine + ("Your Grade is: " & intScore) + vbNewLine + ("Your Average is: " & intAverage)
        Next

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: If you want to show multiple results, you cant do so in one control.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Quite a bit wrong with that code. You should post an example of what you want `lblAnswers` to look like. Please see creating a [mcve] as well as the links above.

Comment: @Plutonix well, a single TextBox with Multiline=True can display a log for example. Might work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

One option is something along the lines of,

```
lblAnswers.Text &= ("Your Grade is: " & intScore & vbNewLine)
```

This will append a new line to the text on each pass through the loop, preserving lines with answers from previous iterations.

Another is to store the results into a `List (Of Integer)` or an array and then build the result string outside of the calculation loop.

Another is to build a result string within the loop and only assign to lblAnswers.Text after you're done.

I don't remember, offhand, if a label will support multiple lines of text like this.  You may find that you need to use a text control instead.

Comment: Side Note: does `&=` actually work? I thought VB.NET had to be `lblAnswers.Text = lblAnswers.Text & ("Your Grade is: " & intScore & vbNewLine)`?

Comment: Yes, `&=` does work in VB.NET and does what you would expect (assigns the concatenation of LHS and RHS to LHS).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the previous value of anything inside a loop, one of the easier means of doing so would be to keep a list you can add to and then reference later.  This way you could get the reference of the index of what just came before, or two times before, etc.

```
Dim scores = New List(Of Integer)

For i = 0 To 4
  Dim previousScore = 0
  Dim score = (i + 1) * 100
  scores.Add(score)
  If ((i - 1) >= 0) Then
    previousScore = scores(i - 1)
  End If

  Console.WriteLine($"Current Score {score} Previous Score{previousScore}")
Next
```

In this example I just create a list of scores outside the loop so it can be referenced to later.  I then iterate a score (I am just taking the iteration plus one times a hundred.  I then add to my scores list.  Then I check to see if it is beyond the first iteration and if so grab the previous iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `List(Of Integer)` to keep track of your inputs. You can easily extract the sum, average, count, min, max, etc. from the List.

Then append the contents of the label each time you add a new line to the top.

```
Private scores As New List(Of Integer)

Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    ' clear scores here or not, depends on whether you want a new list each time
    ' scores.Clear()
    ' clear label here or not
    ' lblAnswers.Text = ""
    For i = 1 To 5
        Dim score = Integer.Parse(InputBox("Enter your grade to continue:", "What's your Grade?"))
        If score < 1 Or score > 100 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a number between 1 and 100")
        Else
            scores.Add(score)
            lblAnswers.Text =
                String.Format("Your grade is: {0}, the sum is {1}, the average is {2}",
                              score, scores.Sum(), scores.Average()) _
                & Environment.NewLine & lblAnswers.Text
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    lblAnswers.Text = ""
End Sub
```

[image]

You may want to add some validation to the input since non-numeric inputs are allowed, but will cause an exception.